# Minimal polynomial of $\alpha = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{48}\right)$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This is a homework problem, so just a nudge in the right direction would be great.

So I am required to show that $\alpha$ is a algebraic over $\mathbb Q$ and show that the degree of its minimal polynomial is a power of $2$.

I know that using De Moivre's Theorem, it can be shown that $\alpha$ is a root of the $48$th Chebyshev polynomial, so $\alpha$ is clearly algebraic, but this is a degree $48$ polynomial which isn't a power of two. Short of brute force factoring $T_{48}$ into irreducibles and hoping that one of them has the right degree, I don't know how to move forward from here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might find inspiration here: https://math.la.asu.edu/~surgent/mat170/Exact_Trig_Values.pdf

Comment: well, you could show this by constructing a regular $96$-gon with ruler and compass.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\omega=e^{i \frac{\pi}{48}}$. Then your cos is an element of $\mathbb Q[\omega]$.

Now $\omega$ is a root of the $96$-th cyclotomic polynomial, which is irreducible and has degree $\phi(96)$.

If you are not familiar with cyclotomic polynomials, try to use the fact that there are $\phi(96)$ primitive $96$-th roots of unity to find $[Q(\omega):Q]$.

Comment: But that is the minimal polynomial for $\omega$, how does that then translate to my $\alpha$, which is the real part of your $\omega$?

Comment: $\alpha = \frac{\omega + \overline{\omega}}{2}$.

Comment: @fretty I meant how does the minimal polynomial for $\omega$ relate to the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$.

Comment: It is possible to find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ but this answer is suggesting you don't have to! The fact that $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ tells you that $\alpha$ must be algebraic. Then showing that it satisfies a min poly of degree a power of two is equivalent to showing that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$ is a power of $2$. But this divides $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}] = \phi(96) = 32$, which is a power of $2$.

Comment: ...in fact it is possible to show that $\alpha$ has minimal polynomial of degree $16$ but this is not necessary here.

Comment: @IAlreadyHaveAKey Since $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}[\omega+\omega^{-1}$ you have $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q[\alpha] \subset \mathbb Q(\omega)$. What is the degree of the outside extension? What does this imply about the inside one?

Comment: If you're allowed to use Galois theory, it's a simple exercise to show that $[\Bbb{Q}(\omega):\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)]=2$. This is easily seen to be sufficient to prove irreducibility.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos 16\alpha=2\cos^2 8\alpha-1=2(\cos^2 4\alpha-1)^2-1=2[(8\cos^4\alpha-8\cos^2\alpha+1)^2-1]^2-1$$
let $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{48}$ and $\cos\frac{\pi}{48}=x$ we have
$$\frac{1}{2}=2[(8x^4-8x^2+1)^2-1]^2-1$$

Comment: Oh that's sneaky. Is there a quick way of telling that that polynomial you have at the is irreducible?

Comment: There is no  sneaky way because we have $$\frac{1}{2}=8192{{x}^{16}}-32768{{x}^{14}}+53248{{x}^{12}}-45056{{x}^{10}}+20992{{x}^{8}}-5120{{x}^{6}}+512{{x}^{4}}-1$$